# pg_dump access denied under windows

Tags: windows, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, pg-dump

I'm trying to create a backup in postgresql 9.3 on windows 7 in two PC

In PC_A I can do without problems

> c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin>pg_dump -U postgres -C -f C:\uti\sample.bak template1

But in the PC_B say `Access is denied`

I try modify the pg_hba.conf file and put trust my ip address and restart postgres service.

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             192.168.0.0/16          trust
```

I can enter psql ok in PC_B with

> psql -U postgres template1

Also I'm running cmd as Administrator

I can create file ok

[image]

What else I'm missing?

Comment: perhaps missing ipv6?

Comment: can you elaborate? because I can connect with user `postgres` using psql ok

Comment: probably not the problem then.

Comment: @Jase well im willing to try anything. I can do backup from pgAdmin. But I need use option `--exclude-table-data` and can't do that inside pgAdmin.

Comment: Can you create a empty file with the same name as the backup you want to make? eg: `rem > C:\uti\sample.bak`

Comment: well that command doesnt create a file but doesnt show error. And i can create a file from file explorer. `echo. 2>EmptyFile.txt` create a file ok

Comment: yeah, but that's not the same file name or location as your pgbackup command is trying to create.

Comment: I include a picture, dont think file creation is the problem

Comment: @Jasen I add another picture I forgot. When say `Access Denied` also say `pg_dump is not a valid Wun32 application`

Comment: The cmd window you attached in question is not administrator.  You need to right-click on cmd and then "run-as administrator".  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947813(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: "Not a valid application", seems odd, perhaps reinstall it, also check any antivirus,  you're attempting to write files to an unusual location, antivirus may have blocked it.

Comment: @Jasen That last tip did the trick. I rewrite `pg_dump.exe` from `PC_A` to `PC_B` and now is working fine. Weird part is if app was wrong why say `Access Denied`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You only need add C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin (postgres path) to PATH in eviroment variables , close the terminal or vscode and check it again , it works for me.